# Is it possible to use `case object` with a type parameter?

Tags: scala

I'm currently learning Scala, and wanted to replicate this Haskell algebraic data type:

```
data Tree = Empty
          | Leaf Int
          | Node Tree Tree
```

This is what I came up with in Scala:

```
sealed trait Tree[T]
case class Empty[T]() extends Tree[T]
case class Leaf[T](value: T) extends Tree[T]
case class Node[T](left: Tree[T], right: Tree[T]) extends Tree[T]
```

However, someone told me that I should use a `case object` for `Empty`, which I suppose is true since it doesn't take parameters - but then again it does require a type parameter.

I tried the following but none of them compile:

```
case object Empty[T] extends Tree[T]
case object Empty extends Tree[T]
case object Empty extends Tree
```

So I'm wondering if there a way to use `case object` in this instance or not.

Comment: A singleton cannot have a type parameter. Maybe you want `case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]`

Comment: `case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]`, since `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type.

Comment: Thank you for the explanatory comments!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A singleton can't be generic because there's only one of them. If you want `Tree` to be covariant (i.e. `Tree[Int]` is a subtype of `Tree[Any]`), then you can define the types as

```
sealed trait Tree[+T]
case object Empty extends Tree[Nothing]
```

Otherwise, leave it as a case class.

Comment: Maybe link the paradigmatic example. https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/library/scala/Option.scala#L345